# Averaging squares

Tags: number-theory

The set of 100 integers $\{1,2,3, \dots 100\}$ are written on a whiteboard. Every minute, a student comes up and erases two distinct numbers $a$ and $b$ from the board, then proceeds to write the quantity $\sqrt{\frac12(a^2 + b^2)}$. After 99 minutes, there is only one number left on the board, $N$. The expected value of $N^2$ can be expressed as a common fraction $\frac{m}{n}$ where $m$ and $n$ are relatively prime integers. What are the last two digits of $m-n$?
$\textbf{(A) } 03 \qquad \textbf{(B) } 65 \qquad \textbf{(C) } 69 \qquad \textbf{(D) } 81 \qquad \textbf{(E) } 99$

I used 50 and 51 because those are the middle numbers and got $\frac{5101}{2}$ and 99. Help?

Comment: Can a number of the form $\sqrt{\frac12(a^2 + b^2)}$ also be erased?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arithmetic%E2%80%93geometric_mean  ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I’ll assume that you intended to imply that the students choose their numbers independently uniformly randomly.

The repeated squaring and taking roots is just a distraction; effectively we’re dealing with the squares of the integers from $1$ to $100$ throughout.

Each random averaging step leaves the expected mean of the remaining numbers invariant. Thus we just have to calculate the initial mean. This is

$$
\frac1n\sum_{k=1}^nk^2=\frac1n\cdot\frac{n(n+1)(2n+1)}6=\frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}6
$$

for $n=100$, which is

$$
\frac{101\cdot201}6=\frac{6767}2\;.
$$

Thus $m-n=6767-2=6765$, and the last two digits are $65$, answer $(\mathbf B)$.